# javax.validation.ValidationException: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception

Tags: spring

I am getting below Exception with my Application , For bean validation in Spring , I am using Spring4.0.2 version.

I am working with weblogic11g application server

javax.validation.ValidationException: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:773)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:331)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForRedefinedDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:278)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:260)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:213)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Failed to load provider from META-INF/services
        at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:121)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence$PersistenceUtilImpl.isLoaded(Persistence.java:278)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:33)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:47)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl cannot be cast to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
        at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:110)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence$PersistenceUtilImpl.isLoaded(Persistence.java:278)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:33)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:47)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

this is my POJO class

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;


public class TestVO extends BaseVO {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Length(max=18)
        @NotNull
        @NotEmpty
        @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9]*")
        private String Id;

                public String getId() {
                return Id;
        }

        public void setId(String Id) {
                this.Id = Id;
        }


}
```

This is My validator Class

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validator;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DataValidator {

        @Autowired(required = true)
        private Validator validator;

        public Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>>  validate(Object tvo) {
                return this.validator.validate(tvo);
        }
}
```

this is my controller class where I am trying to validate my POJO

```
@Autowired
private DataValidator dValidator;

TestVO testVO = testBO.getTest(id);
Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = this.dValidator.validate(testVO);
```

I have updated the application-context.xml with the below validator

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

I have below Jar's in place in my WEB-INF/lib

hibernate-validator-4.0.1.GA.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
j2ee.jar
javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_1-0-2.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
```

Any Help can be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This problem usually happens from conflicts caused by loading classes of the same name, but from different classloaders. I would suggest you to check for any duplicated persistence jar-files (in your case javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_1-0-2.jar) and remove it(them)

Comment: HI Meriton Husaj thanks for your Answer , I tried with removing javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_1-0-2.jar file didn't work out.

Comment: Finally it was fixed after adding new Hiberanate version jar's in class path.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using certain configurations of Hibernate bytecode enhancement, you can also encounter this exception. See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11294